# How to write Batch Apex for counting number of associated Contacts with Account

Tags: apex, schedulebatch

I'm writing batch class to count number of Contacts associated with Account, I want to update custom field in Account object Number_of_Contacts, this field counts the number of contacts associated with each Account. I'm shearing my code ...

```
global class CountNumberOfContacts implements Database.Batchable<SObject> {

global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc)
{
    return Database.getQueryLocator([Select id from Account]);
}

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Account> scope )
{   List <Account> UpAcc = new List<Account>(); 
    List <AggregateResult> acclist = [Select AccountId, count(id) from contact where AccountId in : scope group by AccountId];
    system.debug ('>>>>> AggregateResult >>>>>' + acclist);
    if(!acclist.isEmpty())
    {

        //I'm stuck here... acclist is empty
    }
}

global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc)
{

}
}
```

Comment: If it's an empty list, then there are no contacts for those accounts. There's nothing wrong here.

Comment: I think you are getting scope empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You approach is not optimized. `AggregateResult` will not work if you have more that 50000 records in result.

You can always query child records within a query. `Contact` is child of Account so, we can utilize it as:-

```
    global class CountNumberOfContacts implements Database.Batchable<SObject> 
    {
    
        global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc)
        {
            // Getting child records (Contact)
            //store it in scope.
            return Database.getQueryLocator([Select id, (SELECT id FROM Contacts) from Account]);
        }
    
        global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Account> scope )
        {   
            system.debug ('>>>>> Scope Size >>>>>' + scope.size());
    
            for(Account acc : scope)
            {
                if(acc.Contacts != null)
                {
                    system.debug ('>>>>> Scope Contact size Size >>>>>' + acc.Contacts.size());
                }
            }
        }
    
        global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc)
        {
    
        }
    }
```

`List<Account> scope` will never empty. In above approach no additional queries are needed. Just make sure child relationship of Contact is correct.

Comment: You should change your `execute` method to actually demonstrate how to do the update. Shouldn't add too much to it, especially since you can just remove the debugs, which are worthless IMO.

Comment: @Ashwani Thanks for the code...but no issue with child relationship

Answer (score 0):

I would check out this [post by Jeff Douglas](http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2010/04/12/using-aggregateresult-in-salesforce-com-soql/)

One of the examples is actually very similar to what you're trying to do:

```
Set<id> accountIds = new Set<id>();  
for (AggregateResult results : [select accountId from contact group by accountId])  
  accountIds.add((ID)results.get('accountId'));
```